# CallBack for the recorded block in MediaRecorder

Tags: android, callback, streaming, audio-recording, mediarecorder

I am trying to record a voice from Mic using Media Recorder class. in the mentioned class we have just setOutputFile method to set the output file, but I need to get a buffer of some certain recorded voice, I mean i need something like a CallBack method that return a block of recorded byte at that time and i am going to send the mentioned bytes to another device...

Actually I want to stream and send the recorded voice through socket to another device simultaneously not saving the recorded voice and then read the file and send it, due to it results an unexpected delay...

Comment: If you would like additional help, try answering a few questions so have enough reputation to set a bounty. Or expanding this question with more information about your problem and what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Alireza,

This can be done pretty easily. All you have to do is set up a socket, from that socket you create a ParcelFileDescriptor, then set this file descriptor in setOutputFile. This will set up the streaming part, but then you will have some formatting issues with the file afterwards. This is because MediaRecorder reserves the header space of the file, but only writes it after the stream has finished. In order to have a functional file on the server-side, you will have to parse the header, and write it to the beginning of the file (or buffer).

Good luck,
B-Rad

Comment: hi
Thanks for your reply,

You said I can write it down in a file which is in streaming mode, right? if so can I read a block of stream while the recorder is still recording? or I should wait till writing file gets done?